# openstack-install - specify what MaaS node runs each OpenStack service

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

Is there a way to explicitly state which OpenStack services to deploy on which MaaS node with the openstack-install utility? I'm looking for an option or config file with similar functionality to `JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=maas.node` that is included at the beginning of the installer.

There is a machine with certain NICs that I would like to have the Neutron service deployed to. A previous installation (seemingly) randomly selected a different machine. Removing the Neutron service from that machine and adding it to the correct machine with Juju after the installer finished did not work.

Edit: To clarify, I mean the multiple install without Landscape (only Juju + MaaS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to run the installer with `--edit-placement`

`$ sudo openstack-install --edit-placement`

From there the placement screen will be displayed once bootstrap is complete and let you define what machines has which services and allow you to place them either on bare metal, kvm, or lxc.

Answer (score 0):

The Autopilot will pick any machine with two connected NICs for bootstrap and neutron-gateway. There is no other way to direct placement in Autopilot for now.

Comment: Landscape has picked the correct MaaS node in the past, but not the OpenStack Installer without Landscape. When you say connected does that include NICs that are present but not connected to any networks? The issue is that MaaS detects multiple NICs, however, some of them are not connected to any network. The OpenStack installer seems to use any machine with multiple NICs for Neutron, even if they are disconnected.

Comment: Ah, I don't know about the non-autopilot installer, sorry. It deploys a different topology.